# Identify objects with wrong class according to confusion matrix in R

Tags: r, classification, r-caret

Maybe I have searched for the wrong keywords to find a solution to this problem but so far I haven't found an answer online.

Situation: I have trained a logistic regression model with regularization in R with the CARET package for a two-class classification. With the model I have then predicted the classes of my training and validation set to recieve the confusion matrix and measure the performance of the model.

Question: Now I would like to identify the objects that have the wrong class according to my model. So those that are either predicted as "Yes" when actually they belong to the class "No" and vice versa within the confusion matrix. I would like to do this to inspect the objects in order to improve or alter the features to recieve a better model. What I would like to know is their position whithin the data frame.

My relevant codes:

```
set.seed(1)
datapart <- createDataPartition(m$class, p = .85, list = FALSE)
train <- m[datapart ,]
validation <- m[-datapart ,]

library(glmnet)
set.seed(1)
glmnetcontrol <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, search = "random")
glmnet <- train(class~., data=train, method="glmnet", trControl = glmnetcontrol, metric="ROC")

predict_validation <- predict(glmnet, validation, type="raw")
predict_train <- predict(glmnet, train, type="raw")

quality_glmnet_valid <- confusionMatrix(predict_validation , validation$class)
quality_glmnet_train <- confusionMatrix(predict_train , train$class)
```

Comment: you can try `str(quality_glmnet_valid)` to check what is being returned and use the `$` operator to access your desired elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your prediction are raw probabilities, you'll need them to be a class. The following `>=0.5` conditional check is to convert them to a `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If you want it to be a 1 or 0 (assuming your `class` variable is a binary factor of `1` or `0`) then you can simply subset for the rows where your prediction and the true class labels do not agree with each other.

```
`validation[as.numeric(validation$class) != as.numeric(predict_train >= 0.5), ]`
```

Because you didn't post the data, I have to make some assumption on the structure or format of your data. You can adapt the code to get the rows where there's a misprediction (if they're not a numeric 0 or 1, comment and let me know or post a sample).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, something like that is exactly what I was looking for. However, 'type="raw"' does already return classes. So what I am going to do now is convert the existing classes into numerical arguments to compare them with the true classes, as you explained. Also I am not sure if i would be confortable using the >=0.5 argument to create classes since I dont know which probability threshold was chosen by the algorithm.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful! Yes if it returns a class and not probability there is no need to do the conversion. Then you also do not have to worry about the threshold problem. Most time type=raw do return probabilities though so that’s interesting. Simply check for when the predicted vector do not agree with the true labels (!=)